# Failed to put the turtlebot in full mode

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch running on the turtlebot laptop and the turtlebot dashboard running on my workstation computer but and the icons are green aside from the breakers and the mode icon.  When I attempt to switch the turtlebot's mode to full mode i get the error message:

"Failed to put the turtlebot in full mode: service call failed with error: service [/turtlebot_node/set_operation_mode] unavailable"

Any ideas as to why i cannot switch modes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29648/failed-to-put-the-turtlebot-in-full-mode/) by [mbeard033](https://answers.ros.org/users/1963/mbeard033/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-03-13**:
Is the mode icon grey or red? Do the breaker icons fail to work as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This type of error can occur if you do not have complete network connectivity between computers.  [Guide to Network Setup Troubleshooting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup)

This can also happen if you restart the master without restarting the dashboard.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2